# yum update kernel without removing old?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, kernel, rpm

When I `yum update` it wants to remove the oldest of the 3 kernel I have and upgrade to a new.

Is it possible to get `yum` not to remove old kernels?

Comment: I haven't seen such behaviour tbh. In my opinion, yum is intelligent enough not to do this. Can you show the yum update command output that is asking to remove the old kernel. A quick hack would to be to download the new rpm of kernel and install that using rpm -ivh but I also don't want to do that since yum is a reliable enough tool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `/etc/yum.conf` set `installonly_limit=3`. Quoting from the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html):

> **installonly_limit** Number of packages listed in installonlypkgs to
>   keep installed at the same time. Setting to 0 disables this feature.
>   Default is ’0’. Note that this functionality used to be in the
>   "installonly" plugin, where this option was altered via. tokeep. Note
>   that as of version 3.2.24, yum will now look in the yumdb for a
>   installonly attribute on installed packages. If that attribute is
>   "keep", then they will never be removed.

Comment: You actually want to set installonly_limit to some number *higher* than 3, but this is obviously a good starting point. :)

Comment: @Sandra: Beware, your `/boot` is probably a fairly small partition. You will be sad if you fill it with superannuated kernels.

Answer (score 0):

The `installonly_limit` parameter (from `/etc/yum.conf`) can be increased to 10 or 100 instead of 3. This will allow more kernel versions to be kept.

Comment: Yes, but you will need a _lot_ of space in `/boot` if you start storing lots of kernels. Typically 3 is more than sufficient.